# Formatted memory input

Tags: java, io

I'm reading Eckel's book, IO chapter, and there is the following code (p. 667).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(BufferedInputFile.read("src/io/FormattedMemoryInput.java").getBytes()));
        while(true) {
            System.out.print((char)in.readByte()); // problem line
        }
    } catch (EOFException ex) {
        System.err.println("End of stream");
    }
}
```

This code works great, but if i change `(char) in.readByte()` to `in.readChar()` it prints me some asian symbols `灡捫慧攠楯㬊੩浰潲琠橡癡⹩漮⨻੩浰`. Why is that and why it doesn't print english ASCII symbols out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is that and why it doesn't print english ASCII symbols out?

From `DataInput.readChar()`:

> Reads two input bytes and returns a char value. Let a be the first byte read and b be the second byte. The value returned is:
>   `(char)((a << 8) | (b & 0xff))`
>
> This method is suitable for reading bytes written by the writeChar method of interface DataOutput.

In other words, it's treating your file as if it's UTF-16-encoded - and it almost certainly isn't.

When you want to read text data you *should* use a `Reader` subclass, e.g. `InputStreamReader` wrapped around `FileInputStream`, specifying the appropriate encoding for the input data.